# Hibernate, Postgresql on TomEE

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I tried run my application on tomee 1.6.0 but I have problem with JPA and Hibernate. I'm using postgresql and driver 9.3-1100. I read more tutorials about this theme but my problem is still here. Something I read that my server and commpiler use differnet JVM, but no, I check this possibility. Also I copy jar files from tutorial to tomee/lib directory, but without change. I try hibernate jar files 4.3.0 and also 4.1.4 and same result. Can you tell me what I doing wrong?

I try 
http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-hibernate.html

http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-hibernate/README.html

Log from my TomEE:

```
Feb 10, 2014 11:05:55 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder startInternal
SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /home/leaflock/3.Programovanie/Java/Intellij Projects/Avicularia/target/avicularia: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:897)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:612)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1205)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1051)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWar(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:622)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:593)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.deployment.TomcatWebappDeployer.deploy(TomcatWebappDeployer.java:44)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.deploy(DeployerEjb.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:182)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:164)
    at org.apache.openejb.security.internal.InternalSecurityInterceptor.invoke(InternalSecurityInterceptor.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:182)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:164)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:180)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:182)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:164)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:80)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:212)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:181)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:370)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:181)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:344)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:240)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:86)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:758)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.PersistenceBuilder.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceBuilder.java:150)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:752)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopWebappClassLoader.loadClass(LazyStopWebappClassLoader.java:109)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable.call(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:47)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:115)
    ... 65 more
```

```
[2014-02-10 11:05:55,315] Artifact Avicularia:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2014-02-10 11:05:55,317] Artifact Avicularia:war: javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your libs are OK, maybe is something wrong with your persistence.xml

It must look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="NewFleetSystem" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/YOUR_RESOURCE_NAME</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I guess the error you are facing is just wrong configuration.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please doublecheck that you have the hibernate-entitymanager somewhere in your classpath.

You should have it defined as your WebApps's dependency, as you should try to keep it self-contained. the goal is to have it run on Tomcat, Jetty, Resin and alike.

Be advised that TomEE comes with [openjpa](https://openjpa.apache.org) installed. It is one of the main reasons to use TomEE over Tomcat because it provides a stack of technologies already integrated and tested for compatibility.